# Swift 3 Deleting a sorted table view row and finding the corresponding coreData object

Tags: core-data

I am sure there is an easy solution to this problem but so far I have not found it after looking at many archive questions.  I hope that someone can help as apart from this obvious problem the code works fine!

I have a table of data sourced from coreData which is sorted according to a particular field (not unique).  I want to invite the user to delete an individual table row by swiping left and tapping delete.  I then want to update the table and delete the corresponding coreData object.  The problem is that the correct coreData object to delete is not the index.row of the swiped row in the table as the table has been sorted but the coreData objects remain sorted as they were entered.  I thought of adding a coreData attribute being a unique number series that I could use to identify the object from the index row but I wondered if there is a better solution.  My code to remove the table row is as follows.

Delete row of data from table

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {

                let request: NSFetchRequest<Game> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Game")
                    if let entry = try? managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as [Game] {
                    managedObjectContext.delete(entry[indexPath.row])
                    print("coredata row deleted = ", indexPath.row)

                        do {
                            try managedObjectContext.save()
                            gameRefArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                        } catch let error as NSError {
                            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                        }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching objects using NSFetchedResultsController which is used to manage the results of a Core Data fetch request and display data to the user. Set NSFetchedResultsController delegate to set and implement required methods for NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate in your controller.

Here, to delete object, delete the object from context. Delegate methods will take care of user data to display.

Comment: Thanks.  This is no doubt the area I should investigate but as its new to me it will take some time before I can come back and give feedback.